# How to make KeyboardFocusManager in Java listen to a combination of KeyEvenets?

Tags: java

How to make `KeyboardFocusManager` in Java listen to a combination of `KeyEvents`?

I want to make my program listen to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. How should I do it?

I tried

```
(e.getkeyevent() == "z") {
   if (e.isControlDown()) {
    ....
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Myself, I'd use Key Bindings (Google the tutorial for more on this).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how to put keybindings in a place such that it will always be listened? i mean i have many components in a JFrame

Comment: That's the beauty of Key Bindings -- if done correctly, if using the proper InputMap, your bindings will respond even if the bound component doesn't have focus. For more detailed help, please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.